# how to get the max of summation data from two different column based on data in two different column as well

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have this table

```
No  A1  W1  A2  W2
1   R   4   B   1
2   C   5   A   0
3   B   6   R   0
4   A   1   C   4
```

Then the output should be

```
A   W
C   9
```

Comment: Have you written any code to try this?

Comment: which columns? which data? and what's AW B7?

Comment: Don't you think answer should be `C 9` ?

Comment: What is the real question? What problem are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes it should be C 9, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query should work:

```
  select t.A1 as A, (t.w1+t1.w2) as W
  from t
  inner join t as t1
  on t.A1 = t1.A2
  group by t.A1
  order by (t.w1+t1.w2) desc
  limit 1
  ;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd28b/10/0)

**Note:** From the given description, I think the answer should be:

```
 A | W
 --------
 C | 9
```

Please correct me if I wrong by commenting on this answer.

Hope it helps!